# UCK resume existing project

Tags: customization, custom-distributions, uck

i was making a custom live cd and Ubuntu Customization Kit quit mid way... is there a way i can use the current modified  files i used ?

please help me

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to continue. Open the terminal, type `uck` and press `<tab>` to see the list of commands that you can use. They all have man pages that you can see to figure out what you need. If you tell me at which step exactly your UCK quit I can give you more detailed instructions

Comment: not sure if new post is preferable bt my concern is identical to this. I couldnt find any clue from the man pages / --usage / --help info provided on all the uck-remaster-XXX. power outage in the mid of build process & last items logged were: 
Packing SquashFS image...
Squashfs>=4.1, guest kernel>=2.6.30: Enabling XZ compression for squashfs...
Parallel mksquashfs: Using 2 processors
Creating 4.0 filesystem on /home/harayz/tmp/remaster-iso/casper/filesystem.squash$
^M[\                                                         ]   2400/214537   1%$

how can i resume & where do i pick it back up?